# How to pass keyword arguments with illegal names to a function accepting **kwargs

Tags: python

**Can you help me hack this?** The context is a bit complex to explain, but tl;dr I have to deal with a production system where I cannot install libraries and one of the libraries expects illegal keyword arguments as input.

```
def hack_me(**kwargs):
   if kwargs.get("hack:/me") is not None:
      print("Hacked!")
```

**The objective is that the function above, without modifying it, prints** `Hacked!`.

Comment: `args = {'hack:/me': True}, hack_me(**args)` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While regular arguments can't have any form for their name, expanded arguments using the same syntax as in your function signature (i.e. `**args`) can.

```
>>> args = {'hack:/me': True}
>>> hack_me(**args)
Hacked!
```